# Replace string where it has .rpt

Tags: string, format

I want read a string in java which has something like

```
xyz.rpt
abcde.img
erhteds.doc
aqwer.rpt
```

and modify the string which has `.rpt` in it. If string has `.rpt` at the end I need to change it to `.doc`

```
OUTPUT:

xyz.doc
abcde.img
erhteds.doc
aqwer.doc
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should replace the last occurance of a '.rpt' with a '.doc' 
if you read line by line

```
 StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(yourString);
    b.replace(yourString.lastIndexOf(".rpt"), yourString.lastIndexOf(".rpt") + 1, ".doc" );
    yourString = b.toString();
```

Note This will throw Exceptions if the String doesn't contain '.rpt'